# Looking for lists of student difficulties with electromagnetism, circuits (DC and AC)

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, education

I'm trying to help with an Instructor's Guide for an introductory calc-based physics text, and it would really help if I could locate some lists of typical student difficulties with topics like ...

flux

induced E and B fields

Faraday's law

Lenz's law

DC circuits

AC circuits

Is there a better approach than just Googling "student difficulties with XXX," as I have been trying with rather inconsistent luck?

*Added--*

Thanks for the reminder!  I actually found a copy of Randy Knight's book in the attic that I got from him at an AAPT meeting some years back.  I can't believe I actually located it in my chaos ... great suggestion!

Comment: You may want to check out the standardized tests called IBC-DC and CSEM. Giving the IBC-DC to my students was a depressing but informative exercise. Although I don't think it's a well-constructed test in general, there were certain questions on it that clearly pointed up serious shortcomings in my students' understanding of DC circuits. UW has a physics education research group that has developed a lot of good inquiry-based materials.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the various questions asked by students on the stackexchange itself. Most of the questions asked on this site are by students, and almost 50 percent of those questions are conceptual based. It's really not such a tough task.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Randy Knight's book Five Easy Lessons ([http://www.amazon.com/Five-Easy-Lessons-Strategies-Successful/dp/0805387021](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805387021)). It tries to outline all of the major issues students have in introductory physics, and in my opinion, does a pretty good job. Randy Knight is well known in the Physics Education Research community, and is the author of a popular introductory textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Bill Beaty has a list of [electricity misconceptions](http://amasci.com/miscon/elect.html) online. It is aimed at concepts that are misleadingly or completely incorrectly presented in early education, but since most people at one point or another attended school, they tend to have picked up some of these misconceptions by the time they get to higher education.

Beaty's writing is informal and accessible, and perhaps aimed more at the electrical engineer than the physicist. However, he does have a good way of explaining concepts intuitively. At least in my own experience, an solid, accurate, intuitive understanding is prerequisite to understanding any advanced concept or mathematical analysis. Subtle, fundamental misconceptions can amazingly persist for a long time, masked by rote memorization of equations describing the correct behavior.

The writing is also entertaining, posing questions like, [If a cat gets trapped in a clothes dryer full of nylon pantyhose, which way do the electrons flow?](http://amasci.com/emotor/tribo.html)

In addition to the list of misconceptions above, Beaty also has a large number of [electricity articles](http://amasci.com/ele-edu.html) in general, which seem to cover concepts that he either found interesting, or had difficulty learning, or teaching.